# How could I find files that use certain modules in CPAN?

Tags: perl, cpan

Some modules on CPAN are excellently documented, others.... not so much, but it's usually easy to discern how to use a module via prior art (e.g modules/tests that used the module you're looking to use). I'm wondering what the best way is to find code that uses the code you're looking to use.

**example**

I want to use (maybe?) `Dist::Zilla::App::Tester` for something, but the author has elected not to write any documentation on how to use it, some I'm wondering what path of least resistance is to find code that already uses it.

**please don't answer for this module**

*Give a man a fish; you have fed him for today.  Teach a man to fish; and you have fed him for a lifetime*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [Google Code Search](http://www.google.com/codesearch), trying to search for strings like `"use Dist::Zilla::App::Tester"` (quotes are important).

Answer (score 5):

Use [CPANTS - The CPAN Testing Service web site](http://cpants.perl.org/).

1. [Search for the distribution](http://cpants.perl.org/dist/search)
2. Click `Other dists requiring this`

Here is the page for [Dist-Zilla](http://cpants.perl.org/dist/used_by/Dist-Zilla)

As an aside, you can always read [the source](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/RJBS/Dist-Zilla-4.102340/lib/Dist/Zilla/App/Tester.pm) by hitting the `Source` button on the top of the page on [search.cpan.org](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Dist-Zilla-4.102340/lib/Dist/Zilla/App/Tester.pm). In this case, the package doesn't have much code to begin with. Also, many big modules these days have `::Cookbooks` `::Manuals` or `::Tutorials` [Dist-Zilla has one too](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Dist-Zilla-4.102340/lib/Dist/Zilla/Tutorial.pm#___top)

My guess is `::Tester` just supplies the `dzil test` command through its `test_dzil` sub.

Comment: only problem I have with this is that it tell what dists require what dists. I need to look for a specific module not a dist.

Comment: Cookbooks, Manuals and Tutorials are great for Projects with Phenomenal documentation. Unfortunately all the good documentation for dzil is on [dzil.org](http://dzil.org) and it doesn't cover extending dzil.

Comment: this is god's way of telling you to use `M::I` and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use Google Code Search (Google for that phrase for a link :) ); unioned with pure googling. Search for "use my::module::name" string.

If the module name is not something well-searchable (e.g. too many hits), may be combine with "

Answer (score 0):

For searches over CPAN, I suggest [CPAN Grep](http://grep.cpan.me/) over Google code search.

For more complex searches, I'd write a very small program using [CPAN::Visitor](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CPAN-Visitor/) and a [minicpan](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CPAN-Mini).

For quick dependency checking, I'd use the not-perfect-but-very-good [CPANDB](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CPANDB/).